# Do the needful?

Tags: popularity-contest, comment

**Goal**

Replace all comments in C, C++, or Java Code with the comment `// Do the needful`.

**Specifics**

This coding challenge is a simple one.  Take as input the name of a file.  The input file shall contain C, C++, or Java code.  The code shall contain one or more comments.  The comments can be single line `/* */` or `//` delimited, as well as multi-line `/* */` delimited.  The output of the program should be identical to the input except all of the comments should be converted to `// Do the needful`.

For example if the input file is:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int   result;    // the result of the calculations 
char  oper_char; // the user-specified operator 
int   value;     // value specified after the operator

/* standard main function */     
int main()
{
    result = 0; // initialize the result 

    // Loop forever (or till we hit the break statement) 
    while (1) {
        cout << "Result: " << result << '\n';

        /* This code outputs display and requests
           input from the user */
        cout << "Enter operator and number: ";
        cin >> oper_char;
        cin >> value;

        if (oper_char = '+') {
            result += value;
        } else {
            cout << "Unknown operator " << oper_char << '\n';
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The output of the program should read

```
#include <iostream.h>

int   result;    // Do the needful
char  oper_char; // Do the needful
int   value;     // Do the needful

// Do the needful
int main()
{
    result = 0; // Do the needful

    // Do the needful
    while (1) {
        cout << "Result: " << result << '\n';

        // Do the needful
        cout << "Enter operator and number: ";
        cin >> oper_char;
        cin >> value;

        if (oper_char = '+') {
            result += value;
        } else {
            cout << "Unknown operator " << oper_char << '\n';
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

**Scoring**

This is a popularity contest.  You get two extra votes added to your score if none of the following words appears in your program in any case variation: `{"do", "the", "needful"}`.  Score is number of votes plus bonus if applicable.

**Allowances**

If comments appear in string literals it is acceptable to convert them to `// Do the needful` as well.  After all... you can never have enough needful.

Comment: You know that the bonus is easily acquired by using `"d" + "o"`, `"t" + "he"` and `"need" + "ful"`? Also, does the submission have to be able to deal with *any* valid C, C++ *or* Java code? That's pretty harsh and amounts to writing a lexer for all three languages (I'm thinking about comment literals in strings and vice-versa.) If so, what about 3rd-party lexer libraries?

Comment: This site always makes me laugh at the creative ways people think about problems.  I was not aware that you could cheat the bonus but I am going to leave it as it is.  If the comments appear in literals and strings and it changes them I will allow the solution to stand if it accidentally replaces them.

Comment: What should the program do when a `/* ... */` precedes a non-comment on a line?

Comment: I would put the comment on its own line.

Comment: Do we need to consider cases like `char str[]="/**///";` or a comment-start sequence `/*` appears in a `/*` comment, or a backslash-newline appears in a `//` comment, or a `//` comment within a `/**/` comment?

Comment: nested comments can result in multiple needfuls the more needful the better.  String literals can be replaced too.

Comment: Why make this a popularity contest and not code golf? It works just fine as golf.

Comment: To reward creativity over brevity.

Comment: eventually lots of solutions are based on the same regex replacement. What about some bonus points for non regex solutions?

Comment: I'm curious where this idea came from

Comment: Just random siliness... I hear that phrase a lot and it strikes a nerve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## CoffeeScript (66 bytes)

```
(c)->c.replace /\/\/.*\n?|\/\*[^]*?\*\//g,"// D\o t\he needfu\l\n"
```

This code will parse strings, but there is a good reason. You see, there is a possibility that there is a comment in a template generating C `/**/` comments.

This gets the bonus, as it avoids exact case insensitive matches for `Do`, `the`, and `needful`. It also uses ES5 candle (`[^]`) operator to do stuff. I would put a comment `Do the needful` in this program, but that would remove the bonus.

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 68 characters

```
perl -0pe's@((//).*?(\n)|(/\*).*?(\*/))@\2\4 Do the needful \3\5@sg'
```

This takes some liberties with the specification, and retains the original comment style. This avoids the problem with `/* ... */` comments appearing before the end of the line.

No attempt is made to avoid comments within string literals, and no claim is made for the bonus points.

Comment: I am having a ball using this on source code!

Comment: I would say it *improves* upon some commenting styles.

Comment: You can get the bonus point like this

Comment: perl -0pe 's/((\/\/).*?(\n)|(\/\*).*?(\*\/))/\2\4 D\coo th\coe needfu\cul \3\5/sg'

Comment: Sure, but that's just trivial obfuscation, not really interesting. And we're golfing here, right?

Comment: no golf just popularity plus bonus

Comment: Maybe I missed something. But wasn't `/* standard main function */` supposed to turn into `// Do the needful` instead of `/* Do the needful */`?

Comment: @FDinoff: Yes, that was a liberty I took to simplify the problem, otherwise you have to figure out what to do with code lines where a `/* ... */` comment precedes actual code (you can't naively turn it into a `//` comment).

Answer (score 5):

## Perl

First world anarchy! :)

"you can never have enough needful"

```
#!perl -p0
sub the { s,(?<=\w)(.*)(\n),$1 // do the needful$2,g }
sub needful { s,//.*\n,\n,g,s,/\*.*?\*/,,msg }

do not do the needful
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.x, regex

Since it's not code golf I didn't fuss about code length. Nothing impressive, but I had fun remembering / relearning regex basics.

```
import re
import urllib.request as r
def dTN(filename):
    dtn = re.search(r"(?<=question-hyperlink\">)([A-Za-z \n]*)(?=[?]<)", r.urlopen("http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/").read().decode("utf8")).group(0)
    with open(filename) as f:
        return re.sub(r"//{1}.*", "//{0}".format(dtn), re.sub(r"/\*[A-Za-z \n]*\*/", "// {0}".format(dtn), f.read()))
```

Answer (score 2):

## sed, 90 characters

Could be improved. I learned a lot about sed while making this.

Reads from standard input, outputs to standard output. Assumes valid input - if you have unterminated comments, it won't treat it as a comment.

Tested on GNU sed v4.2.2.

```
s_/\*.*\*/_//_
tg
s_/\*.*$_//_
tl
:g
s_//.*$_// Do the needful_
P
d
:l
s_.*\*/_//_
tg
N
bl
```

And the prize for readability goes to....?

One-liner version:

```
s_/\*.*\*/_//_;tg;s_/\*.*$_//_;tl;:g;s_//.*$_// Do the needful_;P;d;:l;s_.*\*/_//_;tg;N;bl
```

### Explanation

The control flow jumps around a lot, by means of GOTO statements (yes, sed has them!). sed does not have any loops or convenient conditional statements AFAIK.

```
s_/\*.*\*/_//_              # Substitute /* ... */ with //
tg                          # GOTO g if the substitution occured
s_/\*.*$_//_                # Substitute /*...<ENDOFLINE> with //
tl                          # GOTO l if the substitution occured
:g                          # GOTO-LABEL g
s_//.*$_// Do the needful_  # Replace //...<ENDOFLINE> with // Do the needful
P                           # Print the pattern space (current line with substitutions)
d                           # empty the pattern space and move on to the next line
:l                          # GOTO-LABEL l
s_.*\*/_//_                 # Replace ... */ with //
tg                          # GOTO g if the substitution occured
N                           # take another line from input and add it to the pattern space
bl                          # GOTO l
```

Answer (score 2):

### Rebol

It's not code golf, so I'll be wordy.

```
do-the-needful: function [filename [file!]] [
    parse (data: to-string read filename) [
        ; match the pattern in brackets ANY number of times (zero okay)
        any [
            ; seek the parse position up TO one of the following matches
            ; if a match is hit, following code in parentheses is executed normally
            to [
                "/*" (terminator: "*/")
            | 
                "//" (terminator: newline)
            ]

            ; save parse position in start, seek up THRU terminator and leave parse
            ; position at the end of the terminator match (not the beginning as w/TO)
            start:
            thru terminator
            finish:

            ; Do partial replacement within the input; starting at START
            ; but limited to FINISH.  Again, structure in parentheses is exec'd as code
            (
                change/part start combine ["// Do the needful" newline] finish
            )
        ]
    ]
    return data
 ]
```

*(Note: For political reasons, I am pushing COMBINE here, but [it's not standard yet](http://blog.hostilefork.com/combine-alternative-rebol-red-rejoin/).  So if you actually want to run this, use REJOIN.  But I hate REJOIN.  A wart on an otherwise beautiful language!  Tell your friendly neighborhood Red dev leads to listen to me.  Thanks.)*

PARSE is a dialect, or language-within-a-language, in Rebol and Red.  It twists things up, so for instance the symbol types that are used for assignment (the `terminator:` in `terminator: newline`) takes on a new meaning when used in the code-as-data paradigm... it saves the current parse position into a variable with that name.  You can read more about [why it's cool here](http://blog.hostilefork.com/why-rebol-red-parse-cool/).

---

**UPDATE:** Oh all right, I'll golf it too.  In [Rebmu](http://rebmu.hostilefork.com/), 72 chars... using rebmu/args which injects A as the argument:

`pa DtsRDa[anTO["/*"(T"*/")|"//"(Tlf)]SthT F(chpS"// Do the needful^/"f)]d`

Exactly the same program.

Answer (score 2):

### BrainFuck

Yes, BrainFuck is a Turing-complete language.
Good luck for understanding this code.

```
,[.-----------------------------------------------[>+>+<<-]>
>[-<<+>>][-]+<[[-]>-<]>[>,----------------------------------
-------------[>+>+<<-]>>[-<<+>>]<>[-]+<[>-<+++++[>+>+<<-]>>[
-<<+>>]<>[-]+<[>-<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.[-]]>[<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.----
-----------.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------------------------
----------------------------------------------------.+++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++.------------.---.-------------------------
--------------------------------------------.+++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++.---------..-.++.+++++++++++++++.---------.[+++++[,------
------------------------------------],----------------------
-------------------------]>-]<<[-]]>[<++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------------.++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++.---------------------------------------------------------
----------------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.------------
.---.-------------------------------------------------------
--------------.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.---------..-.++.++++++++++
+++++.---------.[,----------]++++++++++.[-]>-]<<[-]<<>-]<<,]
```

Basically, the pseudo-code is :

```
get input_char
while (input_char is not null)
{
  print input_char
  if (input_char is '/')
  {
    get input_char
    if (input_char is '/')
    {
      print '/ Do the needful'
      get input_char until input_char is '\n'
    }
    else
    {
      if (input_char is '*')
      {
        print '/ Do the needful'
        get input_char until input_char is '*' followed by '/'
      }
      else
      {
        print input_char
      }
    }
  }
  get input_char
}
```

Some online interpreter are broken.
[Try it here](http://copy.sh/brainfuck/) with the example given by the OP (ended with *null-char* to break the loop properly) :

```
#include <iostream.h>\n\nint   result;    // the result of the calculations \nchar  oper_char; // the user-specified operator \nint   value;     // value specified after the operator\n\n/* standard main function */     \nint main()\n{\n    result = 0; // initialize the result \n\n    // Loop forever (or till we hit the break statement) \n    while (1) {\n        cout << "Result: " << result << '\\n';\n\n        /* This code outputs display and requests\n           input from the user */\n        cout << "Enter operator and number: ";\n        cin >> oper_char;\n        cin >> value;\n\n        if (oper_char = '+') {\n            result += value;\n        } else {\n            cout << "Unknown operator " << oper_char << '\\n';\n        }\n    }\n    return (0);\n}\0
```